# Shell error when trying to install R from .exe

Tags: r, installation

I'm having trouble installing R.
I remember on my old computer I just double-clicked on the EXE (R-3.6.3-win.exe) and no issues.

I am getting the following error when I double click:

```
ShellExecuteEx failed; code 31.
A device attached to the system is not functioning.
```

If I right-click to Run as Administrator, I still get the "A device attached to the system is not functioning." error. Restarted my computer a couple times of course.

Not sure if it is related, but I get the same error when I try to uninstall Adobe Flash... should have done that last year I guess...

Comment: This Windows answer suggests to press `Win+x` to access the Device Manager and check for any yellow question marks that may indicate a problem with some connection https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update-winpc/a-device-attached-to-the-system-is-not-functioning/500faaeb-fd6e-4cac-bdbe-7a3fc6d56f62

Comment: thanks @EricLeung it looks like that answer is for a different error code, but I tried it anyhow; all clear, I expanded all the device groups and no yellow question marks (or any other indicators). but that was a good idea to check, thank you!